# Making a mistake when praying aloud when you’re alone

Tags: salat, sunnah, sujud

I’ve heard that you can pray the fard of fajr, maghreb and isha aloud when you’re alone. How about when you make a mistake in prayer, do you still have to give Salam to both shoulders and then go back to sajdah or do you give Salam to one shoulder and go back to sajdah. (Also just clarifying, you do this after reciting attahiyyat, and then you come back and say attahiyat again as well as the other dua’s right?

Thanks

Comment: To answer this adequately we need to know your madhhab, whether the mistake was of a kind which needs sujud after tasleem or of a kind that requires sujud before tasleeem. But I guess we have some relevant posts. See for example [https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41517/what-is-the-correct-manner-to-perform-sujud-sahw](what is the correct manner to perform sujud sahw) and [https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30886/how-to-continue-prayer-if-one-found-out-he-missed-or-added-a-raka-or-a-part-of](How to continue prayer if one found out he missed or added a raka ...)